# Surjectivity in proof of Chinese Remainder Thm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So we want to show that $\varphi:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_n, x\mapsto \left([x],[x]\right)$ descends to an isomorphism on $\Bbb Z_{nm}$ if $n, m$ are relatively prime.

It's clear that $\ker \varphi=nm\Bbb Z$ since $n,m$ are relatively prime. Hence $[\Bbb Z:\ker\varphi]=nm$. My lecture notes say this implies surjectivity?
**How does surjectivity follow form that?**

Comment: Hint : What are the cardinality on both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We hence know that $|\text{Im} \phi | =mn$. But $\text{Im} \phi \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n} $, and these two sets have the same finite cardinality, hence...